# How to split C# (Console application) classes into different files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, class

```
namespace APIproject    
{

    public class ApiCallResponse //class1

    class Program //class2
}
```

I have two classes in my code and both are in the same file name Program.cs.
I want to shift my ApiCallResponse class into another file like Program1.cs
And then I want to call the new file Program1.cs into Program.cs to access that class.
How can I do that?

Comment: If you want to move the `ApiCallResponse` class to a new file, call the file **ApiCallResponse.cs**.

Comment: Have you tried making a second file? If so, what errors do you get?

Comment: Right click on the parent folder/object in Solution Explorer and select the option to Add and then select Class.

Comment: Add a new project in your solution, and uses the other project's namespace in the current project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a class in a separate file, which is actually a common practice, you need to add a class file (`*.cs`) and write your code there.

After this, you need to reference a namespace that contains your class and then use your class as usual:

Program.cs:

```
using MySolution.Responses; //This is how you can connect different classes.

namespace MySolution
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var response = new ApiCallResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

../Responses/ApiCallResponse.cs:

```
namespace MySolution.Responses
{
    public class ApiCallResponse
    {
        public ApiCallResponse()
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```